# Best way to store hair colors, eyes colors with django

Tags: django, models

I have a small problem I'd like to know the best way to store eyes or hairs colors with django.

This is what I did before asking myself what the best way :)

```
HAIR_COLORS = (
    ('1', 'braun'),
    ('2', 'blond'),
    ('3', 'red'))


hair_color = models.IntegerField(max_length=1, choices=HAIR_COLORS)
```

Is it a good choice ? Do I have to replace The integerField() by a CharField() with choices like:`

```
HAIR_COLORS = (
    ('braun', 'braun'),
    ('blond', 'blond'),
    ('red', 'red'))
```

In fact I'm not satified, what is your favorite way to implement ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way is:

```
BROWN = 10
BLOND = 20
RED = 30

HAIR_COLORS = (
(BROWN, 'braun'),
(BLOND, 'blond'),
(RED, 'red'))

hair_color = models.IntegerField(max_length=2, choices=HAIR_COLORS)
```

The reason for that is:

1. When you use such numbers you always can insert additional color at any place in choices.
2. Use constants not directly the numbers because in the code when you check or update is far better and explicit to make

> if obj.hair_color == BROWN instead if obj.hair_color == 10

or

> obj.hair_color = BROWN compared to obj.hair_color = 10

Also better naming convention is recommended for example: prefix for the constants like EYES_BROWN and suffix for the choices like HAIR_COLORS_CHOICES. And these statements should reside outside the model for easier import in other parts in the project.

Comment: thank you I love the mixe between Interger storage are globals to allow a better code explanation :)

Answer (score -1):

For those types of definitions, i create a global_defs.py file

global_defs.py:

```
HAIR_COLOR_BROWN = 1
HAIR_COLOR_BLACK = 2
...
```

In models:

```
import global_defs as defs
...
class person(models.Model):
    ...
    color = models.IntegerField(default=defs.HAIR_COLOR_BROWN)
```

In the end you refer to those values by name in all your code, so it's nicely speaking. However in the Database you cannot directly see what each value means.